# Заменить цифры, на цифры с пробелами

Tags: jquery

подскажите как изменить **несколько** цен с одинаковым классом, на цифры с пробелами. Ценик постоянно меняется, единственное, что постоянное это класс

```
<div class="cena_tops">2500000</div>
```

```js
/*
=====================================================
Field Search 7.0
-----------------------------------------------------
Author: PunPun
-----------------------------------------------------
Site: http://punpun.name/
-----------------------------------------------------
Copyright (c) 2018 PunPun
=====================================================
Данный код защищен авторскими правами
*/

var back_url = window.location.pathname;
var back_title = document.title;
var back_speedbar = false;
var resetfilter = false;

$(function() {
 $('body').on('click', '[data-fieldsearch=submit]', function() {
  var $filter_field = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
  
  if(!back_speedbar)
   back_speedbar = $("#dle-speedbar").html();
  
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
  ShowLoading("Ищем... ищем... ищем...");
  
  $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/field_search.php", { form_field : $filter_field, page_url: back_url }, function(data) {
   if(data) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
    var content = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    $("#dle-content1").remove();
    $("#dle-content").css("display", "none");
    $("#dle-content").before("<div id=\"dle-content1\">" + content.content + "</div>");
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, content.url);
   }
  });
  
  HideLoading("");
  return false;
 });
 
 $('body').on('click', '[data-fieldsearch="reset"]', function() {
  resetfilter = true;
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, back_url);
  ShowLoading("Секунду...");
  document.title = back_title;
  
  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] input[type="text"]').each(function(i){
   if($(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
    if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('r-') + 1) {
     var slider = $(this).data("ionRangeSlider");
     slider.update({
      from: slider.options.min,
      to: slider.options.max
     });
    }
    else {
     $('input[type="text"], select').val('');
    }
   }
  });
  
  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] select').each(function(i){
   $(this).children('option').each(function(n){
    $(this).attr('selected', false);
   });
  });

  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] input[type="radio"], [data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh]').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
  $("#dle-content1").remove();
  $("#dle-content").css("display", "block");
  $("#dle-speedbar").html(back_speedbar);
  HideLoading("");
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: должно получиться `2 500 000`?

Answer (score 1):

В `Javascript` есть для этого специальный метод:

вызов:

```
(1234).toLocaleString()
```

вернет:

```
 "1 234"
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].map(el => 
  el.textContent = (+el.textContent).toLocaleString()
)
```

```html
<div class="cena_tops">25000000</div>
<div class="cena_tops">250000000</div>
<div class="cena_tops">2500000000</div>
<div class="cena_tops">25000000000</div>
```

Comment: @Never3D я не понял

Comment: у меня есть фильтр, и главная страница, при нажатии на кнопку подобрать, высвечивается результаты, так вот не работает скрипт

Comment: @Never3D ну куда нибудь результат сохраните, чтобы посмотреть,  скрин или лог ошибок

Comment: прикрепил скрипт фильтра

Comment: ошибок нет, просто ajax не обрабатывает выше скрипт